# PHP For loop with checkboxes not giving expected output

Tags: loops, for-loop, checkbox

I am getting some unexpected output from the following code and can't figure out what the problem is.

```
   <?
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    exit;
    }
    echo "<form action='test1.php' method='post'>";
    for ($i=0;$i < 10;$i++) {
    echo "<input type='text' value='$i' name='field[]'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='cbox[]' value='0'>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='cbox[]'><br>";
    }
    echo "<br><input type='submit' name='submit' value='go'>";
    ?>
```

If I run this, check on say number 4 and 6, I get this output:

```
Array
(
    [field] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 6
            [7] => 7
            [8] => 8
            [9] => 9
        )

    [cbox] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
        )

    [submit] => go
)
```

Why is cbox not giving me a result of 1 next to the 4 and 6 as I would expect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is cbox not giving me a result of 1 next to the 4 and 6 as I would expect it?

Because you have a hidden field with the same name and value 0 in those “positions.”

Checkbox values are only submitted if the checkbox was checked. So when you check checkbox 4 (the fifth), you have four times your hidden input and four checkboxes before that. Since none of the checkboxes are checked, four times 0 is submitted (the hidden fields). Now you check the fifth checkbox, so now the value of the hidden field *and* the checkbox is submitted. We had four 0 already, now we have another 0 and then a 1 - makes five 0, followed by a 1, so the 1 ends up at array index 5.

Works as designed.

I would do away with the hidden fields completely, and specify the index to use instead - `name='cbox[0]'`, `name='cbox[1]'`, ...

You will still only get values for those that were checked - but now you have the index association match those of the text fields automatically (same naming scheme for those, too, of course.)

Comment: I added the hidden field because of another Stackoverflow question/response. I want to take the output and dump into a database and put either a 0 (for unchecked) or 1 (for checked) into my database field. If I left out the hidden, I would have gotten:  [cbox] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
)

If this makes any sense.

Comment: Make it like I said, name the fields `cbox[0]` etc. Then in a for loop from 0 to x you check if the correspodning entry in $_POST['cbox'] is set - if yes, you put 1 into an array, otherwise 0 ... and there you have the "complete set".

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to force the array index in the checkboxes and hidden fields like this:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);
  exit;
}
echo "<form action='test1.php' method='post'>";
for ($i=0;$i < 10;$i++) {
  echo "<input type='text' value='$i' name='field[]'>";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='cbox[$i]' value='0'>";
  echo "<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='cbox[$i]'><br>";
}
echo "<br><input type='submit' name='submit' value='go'>";
?>
```

This way your checkbox will override the hidden field value if you check it. If you omit the $i in the field names, the values will sum up in the output array (as you can see you had 12 values in the output array, 10 from the hidden fields and 2 for the checked checkboxes).

Comment: Ah... did not even notice it went to 11 fields on cbox! Thank you!